# AngularJS: Trying to get data from variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

cartController in AngularJS:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.refreshCart = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/cart')
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data;
        });
};
    $scope.removeFromCart = function(productId) {
        $http.delete('/delete/' + productId)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.refreshCart();
            });
    };
    $scope.addToCart = function(productId) {
        $http.put('/add/'+ productId)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.refreshCart();
        });
    };
});
```

First HTML file (here everything works):

```
<a href = "#" type="button" class="btn btn-info" th:attr="
                       ng-click='addToCart(' + ${product.id} + ')'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            Add to cart</a>
```

Second HTML file:

```
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" ng-app="demo">
<script src="http://localhost:8080/cartController.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="Hello">
    (...)
 <tbody ng-repeat="item in items.cartItemList">
            <div class="row">
                    <h4 class="nomargin">{{item.product.name}}</h4>
                    <p>{{item.product.description}}</p>
            </div>
        <td data-th="Price">{{item.price}} PLN</td>
        <td data-th="Quantity">{{item.quantity}}</td>
        </tbody>
(...)
```

So what i need to do is:

1) Hit the button in first HTML file, and load JSON to $scope.items (it works).

2) Show the second HTML file, load JSON from $scope.items, and view this JSON to user.

But when I get the second HTML file and try to show data, the $scope.items is empty. Can you help pleae ?

Comment: Why does your "second" HTML file contains a `html` tag + `ng-app`attribute? Do you know how SPA works?

Comment: Hmm should I delete it ? SPA ? Never heard; <

Comment: I removed ng-app attribute but still doesn't work properly,

Answer (score 1):

Do you get console errors in your browser? Maybe you have to define `items` on the controller as empty array like in the example below ...

```
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    //define empty array
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.refreshCart = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/cart')
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data;
        });
    };
    //...
}
```

Comment: No, I don' get any errors. I tried your solution, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I suspect the error might be in ng-app="demo" (in both files).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use broadcast and emit. Pass data between the controllers using these. You should use $broadcast if you want to pass data from parent controller to child controller. And emit if the other way around.